# MassTransit error handling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, msmq, masstransit

Using MassTransit v2.9.0.0 and MSMQ and IWindsorContainer

```
var bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
        {
            sbc.UseMsmq(configurator =>
            {
                configurator.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();
            });
            sbc.VerifyMsDtcConfiguration();
            sbc.UseJsonSerializer();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom(String.Format(new WebConfig().Get<string>("msmqNameTmpl"), Environment.MachineName));


            sbc.Subscribe(x => x.Handler<TicketOfferTransferMessage>(msg =>
            {
                var handler = container.Resolve<IHandle<TicketOfferTransferMessage>>();                    
                handler.Handle(msg);
                container.Release(handler);
            }));                                                                 
        });

        container.Register(Component.For<MassTransit.IServiceBus>().Instance(bus));
```

I'm initializing the queue and subscribing as above. This all works fine as long as the Handle method doesn't throw any exceptions. In this case the message is moved to the xxxxxxx_error queue.

Ideally I'd like to subscribe to the error queue OR to an erroor event and trigger a notification that the initial message failed to complete successfully.

I'd also like to be able to move the message back to the primary queue.

The MassTransit v2 docs have [this](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/v2-master/overview/errors.html) to say on error handling.

Comment: It works nicely in MT 3, you can consume `IFault<T>` events. Not sure of migration is an option for you but you will have to give up MSMQ.

Comment: In the end I've used MSMQ Triggers and Rules to execute a program which notifies me when a message enters the error queue